# execute cut command inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Every line printed with the echo includes the forward slashes for the directories that the given files are in. I am trying to cut the forward slashes using the cut command but it is not working. The files are gzipped so they have the .gz extension.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /data/logs/2017/month_01/201701*
do
echo $filename
cut $filename -d '/' -f1
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would `echo "$filename" | cut ...` help ?

Comment: please give an example of the input you have and the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

The order of commands is wrong. You need to *stream* the string input to the `cut` command via pipe(`|`) or here-strings(`<<<`).

```
echo "$filename" | cut  -d '/' -f1
```

(or)

```
cut -d '/' -f1 <<<"$filename"
```

(or) using here-docs

```
cut -d '/' -f1 <<EOF
$filename
EOF
```

data

And don't forget to double-quote variables to avoid [Word-Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) done by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming filename is `/a/b/c.gz` you just want `c.gz` ?

Well there's two very easy answers:

```
basename $filename
```

The other is:

```
echo ${filename##*/}
```

The latter make use `bash`'s built-in string delete parameter expansion.

Another way of solving your problem, is you could change directory first, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

pushd /data/logs/2017/month_01
for filename in 201701* 
do
    echo $filename
done
popd
```

Reference:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

(EDIT: Fixed typo identified by @123)

Comment: Think you're missing a `/` in the parameter expansion example.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested b @lnian cut command used with echo command via pipe sign 
For getting only file name with your script you need to use.

cut with -f1 option will get first value before / which would give blank so you need to get last value from the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /data/logs/2017/month_01/201701*
do
echo "$filename" | rev| cut  -d '/' -f1
done
```

rev command reverse the filename so you will get last value which is your filename